# Is there a way to make a square pattern mask that matches the size of my image in python?

Tags: python, mask

I was wondering if there is a way to make an array/column like [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255....] that repeats until a certain length (length of a imported image) for every row/array. The goal of this will be to make an image that will show 255 as white "pixels" and 0 as the black "pixels". Is this possible?

[proposed mask concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhMYh.png)
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrhG4.png)

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import data
from skimage import io

path = r'C:\C:\Python36\bmp_files\slide_3.png'
sz = 400
image = data.astronaut()
patch1 = image[250:250+sz,250:250+sz,:]
patch1.shape
#(48, 48, 3)
mask = np.tile(np.array([[[1],[0]],[[0],[0]]],dtype=np.uint8),(sz/2,sz/2,3))
mask.shape
#(48, 48, 3)
print (mask)
patch2 = patch1 * mask
patch12 = np.hstack((patch1,patch2))`
```

Comment: Are you trying to replicate some example documentation?, by now I can not find any similar. Maybe you are trying to apply some combination of algorithms that I do not know

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the question and hope it is easier to understand now. Pretty much just asking how to use np.tile to make an "image" with only gray level of 0 and 255. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes just replicating the example document would be great

Comment: I have found [this](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_floodfill.html#) but I can not related to your work, this is why I asking you if you are trying to run some example

Comment: Okay thank you. I will take a look at this and let you know.